# Select parent element in stylus

Tags: html, css, stylus

I'm using the css preprocessor Stylus and i'm trying to select the first parent of an element.

```
<li><span class="correct">Ja</span></li>
<li><span class="inCorrect">Nee</span></li>
<li><span class="inCorrect">Mss</span></li>
```

I want to style the li element depending on the class of the span element.

Is this possible?

Comment: I know, but it's worth asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in CSS, and in Stylus as it is just compiled into CSS.

However, you could somewhat emulate it in some cases, when you want to change just how the parent *looks*: you can use another element after the one with the class, and stretch in onto the parent, see this demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/7638112

The HTML you'd need there:

```
<ul>
<li><span class="correct">Ja</span><span class="helper"></span></li>
<li><span class="inCorrect">Nee</span><span class="helper"></span></li>
<li><span class="inCorrect">Mss</span><span class="helper"></span></li>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.helper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.correct + .helper {
    background: lime;
}

.inCorrect + .helper {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#relative-reference

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#selector-bif

```
yourFunc(yourClass)
  if yourClass=='inCorrect'
    color = green

.inCorrect
  ../
    yourFunc(selector())
```

Something like that should work! Check the docs and play with it.

Answer (score -4):

This might help...

```
li<.correct
{
   //write your style here
}
```

Comment: I don't even use Stylus and I know this is complete, utter nonsense.